# Tabulator - Specifying Formatter at a cell level rather than column

Tags: tabulator

I have a simple table with 2 columns Property Name and Value which display the properties of the selected object. It is working fine.

The properties could be things such as name, height, width, colour.

I would like the user to be able to edit the cells, but the appropriate formatter to apply to the cell they are editing.

For example, if editing the name cell it would just be text. height would be numeric, colour would be colour, visible maybe a tick/cross or a select.

Looking at the documentation it is geared (sensibly) to have 1 formatter to a column as it assumes that columns data will all be of the same type.

Is it possible to have a mix of formatter types for a single column?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can only assign formatters at the column level not the cell level, but there would be nothing to stop you creating your own custom formatter function that output the correct formatter element depending on the type of cell it was applied to.

There are detailed instructions on creating your own custom formatters in the [Custom Formatter Documentation](http://tabulator.info/docs/4.9/format#format-custom)

Comment: thanks for the response. I had a quick look, and I was hoping I would be able to do something like this for the custom formattor function (in pseudo code) : If cell.getValue().startsWith("#") return "colour", else if cell.getValue()=="true" return tickCross  etc..... the return values being the type of formatter I want to use from the built in ones. This didn't seem to work, should it?

Comment: Not it won't work, that would set the value of the cell to the string you return

Comment: So it sounds like I wouldn't be able to use the inbuild formatters with a custom formatter in the way I want?

Comment: That is correct, you wouldn't be able to use built in formatters you would need to use a custom formatter that replicated their functionality based on case. You could easily build this by copying the existing formatter functions from the source into your custom formatter

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation. Marked as answered. It would be handy if you could point me to the source js file that has the formatters in to copy?

Comment: /src/JS/modules/format.js in the github repo for Tabulator. At the end of the file is a default formatters object that contains all the formatter functions